# Windows Server Core 2016 RODC consistent replication issues not persistent with desktop WIndows Server deployments:

Tags: windows, active-directory

I've been tasked with updating all of our remote site DCs and am building Server Core 2016 RODCs. Every server core deployment I've done joins the domain properly, but then gives error 58 in repadmin. I do not have any errors when I deploy a full GUI Windows server.

These remote sites connect back via MPLS tunnels. No ACLs on the VLANs and everything will work properly so long as it is a full desktop. I've tried disabling the firewall and can see that traffic is passing across the network.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue. A GPO had been created that was applying the DNS suffix under Computer Configuration / Policies / Administrative Templates / Network / DNS Client that had a character wrong in the domain name and resulted in a config error for lookups.